# Python 3.8 / Tkinter: items in canvas cannot be bound to a function from within a loop

Tags: canvas, tkinter, bind

I cannot understand why this small piece of code works **well for green points** (when I click on it, displayed tags are OK) **but not at all for red ones** (tags are always the same although the loop : the latest one in).

Is it a bug? Or do I miss something?

```
import tkinter as tk

def show(event, p, tag):
    print(f"{p=}\n{tag=}")


centers = [[50, 50], [90, 50]]

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

p1 = canvas.create_oval(20,10,30,20, fill='green',tags=('point_green_1', 'draw'))
p2 = canvas.create_oval(50,10,60,20, fill='green',tags=('point_green_2', 'draw'))
canvas.tag_bind(p1, '<Button-1>', lambda event: show(event, p1, ('point_green_1', 'draw')))
canvas.tag_bind(p2, '<Button-1>', lambda event: show(event, p2, ('point_green_2', 'draw')))

for idx, center in enumerate(centers):
    tag= f'point_{idx}'
    p=canvas.create_oval(center[0] - 5, center[1] - 5, center[0] + 5, center[1] + 5, fill='red',
                         tags=(tag, 'draw'))
    canvas.tag_bind(p, '<Button-1>', lambda event: show(event, p, tag))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code as this

```
import tkinter as tk

def show(event, p, tag):
    print(f"{p}\n{tag}")


centers = [[50, 50], [90, 50]]

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas()
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')

p1 = canvas.create_oval(20,10,30,20, fill='green',tags=('point_green_1', 'draw'))
p2 = canvas.create_oval(50,10,60,20, fill='green',tags=('point_green_2', 'draw'))
canvas.tag_bind(p1, '<Button-1>', lambda event: show(event, p1, ('point_green_1', 'draw')))
canvas.tag_bind(p2, '<Button-1>', lambda event: show(event, p2, ('point_green_2', 'draw')))

for idx, center in enumerate(centers):
    tag= f'point_{idx}'
    p=canvas.create_oval(center[0] - 5, center[1] - 5, center[0] + 5, center[1] + 5, fill='red', tags=(tag, 'draw'))
    canvas.tag_bind(p, '<Button-1>', lambda event, p=p, tag=tag: show(event, p, tag))

root.mainloop()
```

The problem is in the line where you bind the red button event `canvas.tag_bind(p, '<Button-1>', lambda event: show(event, p, tag))`

at lambda you have to pass the args `p=p, tag=tag` too, if not in the callback are passed the refereces of the `tag` and `p` variables that are used in the `for loop`. This will cause that each time that you change that variables they will change in the callback functions too and it will generate the `"error"` that you are seeing. Instead, if you set the varibles inside `labmda` you will pass at the callback new variables that will not be touched again.

Comment: Thanks for this. Perfectly clear. I missed something :)